# How to open file in new tab instead of download when submitting form?

Tags: 8, files

The code below downloads the current file, I need it to open the file in a new tab, what needs to be added in order to do so?

```
public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
     $filename = '/var/www/html/web/modules/custom/custom_module/sample.pdf';
     $response = new BinaryFileResponse($filename);
     $response->setContentDisposition(
          ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
          'sample.pdf'
     );
     $form_state->setResponse($response);
```

Comment: That’s not possible, tabs can only be opened by client-side code

Answer (score 0):

As @clive points out, this cannot be done on the server side. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19295410/submit-form-to-new-window-tab) post for a javascript based solution. You need to [attach the javascript](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-module) to your form during build. See below for an example of form build with a javascript attached to the submit element:

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  // Assuming you are extending core \Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase class
  // and prior the lines below you built your form elements.
  $form['actions']['#type'] = 'actions';
  $form['actions']['submit'] = [
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => $this->t('Download file'),
    '#button_type' => 'primary',
    '#attached' => [
      'library' => 'your_module/submitToNewTab'
    ]
  ];

  return $form;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to open the results of a form in a new tab, like this:

```
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $form['#attributes'] = ['target' => '_blank'];
  ...
}

public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  ...
  $form_state->setRedirect(
    'skilling.calendar_planner',
    ['node' => $calendarNid, 'startDate' =>  $startDate]
  );
```

}